# Redmine keeps asking to run bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, redmine, gemfile

I'm performing **bundle install** of Redmine on a server in China, and I have replaced https://rubygems.org with https://gems.ruby-china.org/ both in gemfile and mirror as suggested like this:

```
gem sources --add https://gems.ruby-china.org/ --remove https://rubygems.org/
```

And also in my Gemfile, so it looks like this:

```
#source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://gems.ruby-china.org/'
```

But after running **bundle install** which is reinstall actually I'm getting message below:

> Your bundle is locked to json (1.8.6), but that version could not be
>   found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't
>   changed sources, that means the author of json (1.8.6) has removed it.
>   You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of json
>   (1.8.6) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
>   (Bundler::GemNotFound)

While I can confirm that 1.8.6 is installed like this:

```
gem list
...
json (1.8.6, 1.8.3)
```

And like this:

```
bundle show json
/home/redminedev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/json-1.8.6
```

This is the listing of rvm list gemsets:

```
rvm list gemsets

rvm gemsets

=> ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.3@global [ x86_64 ]
```

I tried deleting .bundle directory, deleting gemfile, purging and reinstalling all gems... Nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using rvm?

Comment: Yes, you can conclude that based on /.rvm/ listed in post.

Comment: can run this command "rvm list gemsets" and paste output?

Comment: I've edited my question, added rvm list gemsets

Comment: now it's working for you?

Comment: Not working I didn't do anything except  rvm list gemset

Comment: Man, No need to add this rvm list gemsets just run this command on your console and paste the output here

Comment: rvm list gemsets

rvm gemsets

=> ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.3@global [ x86_64 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what eventually fixed my problem, thanks for atombender's answer here:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/5068#issuecomment-259580704

I've performed:

```
bundle install --deployment
```